# Floating an element that comes afterwards normal content

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem. In the following markup, there's an aside-element which contains additional information for the user which I would like to display as shown in the attached picture (right floated).

```
<section>
    <h2>site title</h2>
    <p>that's the site's main content</p>
    <aside>
        <h3>other stuff</h3>
        <div>cloud tag</div>
    </aside>
</section>
```

However, I don't want to place the aside-element before the h2-element and just right-float it. I know this would work, but somehow it would seem wrong to me. One could say, that the search-engines know that it's lesser-important content, since it's contained in an aside-element.

But I would also like the aside-element behave, that when the page's width is smallered (e.g. smaller devices), the aside element stays BELOW the main content.

So my question is: Is there any possibility to float the aside-element as shown in the picture, without manipulating the markup-order (adding helping div's is okay, i guess).

Thanks already, looking forward.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your main content in a div, and then add `float: left` to both the main div and your aside element. Then, just use the `margin` property to space them appropriately.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="main">
        <h2>site title</h2>
        <p>that's the site's main content</p>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <h3>other stuff</h3>
        <div>cloud tag</div>
    </aside>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    float: left;
}
aside {
    float: left;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFEYY/).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was quite busy. That one seems legit to me, but didn't work once I set the width of .main to 100%.
Gave you the green check mark as I didn't specify my question precisely.